# DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport not working

Tags: ms-access, vba

I don't understand if I run the saved import manually it works but when it is in the vba code is it just doesn't. When I step through it stops as if to run it but it never does anything and it just moves on.

`DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "Import-DES_INV_TSR_ACIPS_FINAL"`

Any help please.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem is that it would not let me use a saved import that deleted and recreated the table. I had to create a new one that imported into an existing table.

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept your own answer as well. It is encouraged, even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that it would not let me use a saved import that deleted and recreated the table. I had to create a new one that imported into an existing table.